# Trading toolbox: "Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback " only getting when running standalone program

Tags: matlab, event-handling, interactive-brokers

I have a Matlab object with the following function:

```
   function obj = request_historical(obj,ticktype)
        startdate = floor(now)-1500;
        enddate = floor(now);
        period = '1 day';
        tradehours = false;
        eventhandler = 'IB_histHandler';

        d2 = history(obj.ib,obj.ibContract,startdate,enddate,ticktype,period,...
        tradehours,eventhandler);
   end
```

Then I call that function. The function sends historical financial data and it's handled by another function "IB_histhandler". The function is located in the same directory as the standalone program.

It works fine when running it through the the Matlab program using the workspace, but whenever I run the Standalone compiled program I get a bunch of warnings:

```
Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback.
> In pause (line 21)
  In IB_socket (line 432)
  In start (line 13)
  In tradingbot (line 31)
Error using comeventcallback (line 24)
Error firing event 'historicalData' to 'IB_histHandler'.
```

it's like my standalone exe program can't find the "IB_histhandler" function like the program finds it when it's run through MATLAB using the workspace.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question,  but I generally put my event handlers into static methods of my base class.  This makes it simple to pass the handle through the toolbox.

Create a persistent variable (matlab's version of a static property) in this static method that holds an object that can raise events that the base class can subscribe to.  For example...

```
methods (Static)

    function HandleEvents(newObject,varargin)

        persistent obj
        % obj is filled during base object construction...
        if nargin==1
            obj=newObject;
            return
        end % Rest of the function follows...
```

You can assign a property in the base class to hold a pointer for this object.

Keeps everything wrapped in one class and works well for me.